# C# equivalent of Java instance initializer

Tags: c#, java

In `Java` instance variables can be initialized by an initialization block as shown below:

```
class Example {
    private int varOne;
    private int varTwo;

    {
        // Instance Initializer
        varOne = 42;
        varTwo = 256;
    }
}
```

Is there an equivalent construct in `C#`?

**[Edit]** I know that this can be inline with the instance variable declaration. However, I am looking for is something similar to the static constructor in `C#` but for instance variables.

Comment: Point of pedantry: instance initialiser blocks and instance field initialisation are executed by the constructor immediately *after* calling super.

Comment: @Tom - You are right about the calling order. The source code comment is removed.

Comment: Why not just make it a method and call it from the constructor, if that is what happening behind the scene anyway?

Comment: @toxvaerd - Sometimes we can't create constructors (e.g. anonymous class in Java). But, I think you can use different constructs like delegates in C# to do what anonymous classes are used for in Java (e.g. GUI event handlers). Just wondering if there is an equivalent construct.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There really is no equivalent in C#.  C# has only 2 ways to initialize instance varibles

1. In the constructor
2. By explicitly initializing the variable at it's declaration point

There is no way to do an initialization after the object is created but before the constructor runs.

Answer (score 7):

Create an instance constructor that any other local constructor will call in the initialization list:

```
private Example ()
{
    //initialize all fields here
}

public Example (/*list of parameters*/) : this()
{
    //do specific work here
}
```

If the default constructor is already required by the logic of the application, then susbstitute

```
private Example ()
```

with

```
private Example (object dummy)
```

and, of course, accordingly modify the initilization call.

Comment: unfortunately that doesn't let you have multiple instance initializer blocks... but for the common case would be reasonable.

Comment: Curious - what is TofuBeer? and also, why would you want multiple instance initializer blocks?  For the latter - it seems it would lead to confusion with blocks scattered throughout the class code, separate from constructors and separate from the member decls.

Comment: a concrerte example - there is a private readonly field I need to initialize based on some class methods that are unavailable at the static initialization.

Comment: In Java (static/instance) initialization block is usually (!) used in conjunction with static/instance variables that need some sort of special initialization incantation. Using initializer blocks allows you to keep the initialization code close to the fields being initialized this way, thus lessening the cognitive distance between declaring something and setting up it's value. It's not perfect, but sometimes necessary

Answer (score 1):

If this is what you want for specific case then extent that it's possible is as below :

```
class Example {
    public int varOne;
    public int varTwo;

    public Example(){
        Console.WriteLine("varOne : " + varOne + ", varTwo : " + varTwo);
    }

    public void getValues()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("varOne : " + varOne + ", varTwo : " + varTwo);
    }
}

static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Example e = new Example{ varOne = 42, varTwo = 256};
        e.getValues();
    }
```

Here, then there is a constraint that you would require instance variables to be public.

Comment: It's a kluge that can never work in a deeply object oriented encapsulation env. It's not practical.